# Only white screen appears when I run my app (using view binding) in AVD

Tags: java, android

I was creating an application but when I run my application using AVD, it shows a blank screen.

I don't know what is the reason. Please help me solving this question.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(MainActivity.this,R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        binding.textView.setTextSize(18);
        for (int i = 0; i < questionBank.length;) {
            Questions questions = questionBank[i];
            binding.textView.setText(questions.getAnswerResId());
            binding.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (questions.isAnswerTrue()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.correct_answer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.wrong_answer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        binding.button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!questions.isAnswerTrue()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.correct_answer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.wrong_answer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    


}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for

```
setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```

DataBinding.setContentView() is enough.

Answer (score -1):

Or u can code it Like I do. Also Im using kotlin

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
```

Comment: He's using java and you are telling him kotlin code!!!

Comment: Wooow, Good Job Singh  Like there is a big difference between java and kotlin. They are same

Comment: Actually I don't have any idea about Kotlin that's that's why I commented this

Comment: Easy, kotlin is short version of java. Beside of writing a long code of java u can write short one using kotlin. If u know java , kotlin will be a piece of cake to learn.